# Propriedade '_$visited' em objeto JavaScript no retorno da função map() do Obervable

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, jax-rs

Tenho um WebService implementado com `JAX-RS` e estou o consumindo com um serviço(`utilizando Angular 2`)

Segue o serviço:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModeloService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Modelo[]> {
    return this.http.get(myEnvironment.MODELO_SERVICE_PATH)
      .map(res => <Modelo[]> res.json());
  }

}
```

`Modelo` é essa minha classe:

```
export class Modelo{
  id: number;
  type: string;
  size: number;

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

Acontece que o retorno da função `map()`, monta o seguinte objeto `JavaScript`, ou seja, ela insere essa propriedade `_$visited` : true:

```
{
  "id": 28,
  "type": "type",
  "size": null,
  "_$visited": true
}
```

Essa propriedade **"_$visited"** não faz parte do meu modelo lá do lado do WebService, nem do lado do front-end, se eu consumo esse WebService por um client Rest(utilizo o **Restlet Client)**, o json retornado é o esperado ou se eu logar o retorno da própria função res.json():

```
{
  "id": 28,
  "type": "type",
  "size": null
}
```

Queria saber, primeiro de onde vem essa propriedade `"_$visited"` e qual a melhor forma de sumir com ela, pois quando vou enviar esse objeto pro meu web service de novo, ele vai com essa propriedade.

Comment: Em uma pesquisa rápida pela Internet, vi que o lugar que usa essa propriedade "_$visited" é o Primefaces, mais especificamente o PrimeNG. Você está usando essa biblioteca?

Comment: Sim, estou usando essa biblioteca? pode me passar a referência?

Comment: Cheguei nisso através dessa issue no GitHub https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1937 provavelmente você não precisa se preocupar com essa propriedade, é apenas um controle do PrimeNG.

Comment: acontece que ela é setada e quando vou enviar um post com esse mesmo objeto pro web service, dá erro lá do outro lado.

Comment: Acredito que qualquer implementação que você esteja utilizando tem alguma maneira de dizer para os objetos ignorarem as propriedades que não são mapeadas no seu Backend. Por exemplo o Jackson tem @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true), dê uma olhada.

Comment: Não conhecia essa annotation, vlw brother. deu certo.

Comment: Redigi uma resposta para ajudar quem mais tiver esse problema. Se puder aceitá-la. Abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa propriedade é adicionada pelo [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) para realizar alguns controles da biblioteca. Teoricamente ela não deve influenciar no envio de requisições para o seu backend.

Porém se o backend estiver lançando exceções dizendo que não conhece a propriedade, você pode usar uma anotação da sua biblioteca JSON para ignorar essas propriedades desconhecidas.

Um exemplo de anotação do Jackson na classe de comunicação:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Dessa maneira a biblioteca não tentará realizar o parse dessa propriedade.